# Hangman, replace hidden word with correctly guessed letter

Tags: java

I am new to java and for a class I am supposed to create a hangman style game. I figured out the how to pull and mask a word from a word list, but cannot replace the masked word with the newly guessed letter, nor will it store the letters guessed correctly or incorrectly to the String variable. My teacher advised we cannot use arrays, we have to use a char and have it search the Strings... Any help would be appreciated!

This is for the input guess:

```
guess = keyboard.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(guess)){
               for (int l = 0; l < guessedLetters.length(); l++){
                  if (guessedLetters.charAt(l) == guess){
                  System.out.println ("==> a was already guessed.");
                  }
                  else if (Character.isAlphabetic(guess)){
                     for(int m = 0; m < guessedLettersInc.length(); m++){
                        if (guessedLettersInc.charAt(m) == guess){
                           guessedLettersInc = guessedLettersInc + guess;
                  }}}
                  else{
                     hiddenWordGame = hiddenWordNew;
                     guessedLetters = guessedLetters + guess;
                  }}}
            else{
               System.out.println("Not a letter, guess again:");
            }
```

And then for the checking the hidden word and replacing the "-" with the correct letter I have:

```
   public static String hiddenWordGame(String wordLookup, String hiddenWordGame, String guess, String hiddenWordNew)
   {
   
     for (int k = 0; k < wordLookup.length(); k++)
        if(wordLookup.charAt(k) == guess.charAt(0)){
           hiddenWordNew += guess.charAt(0);
           }
             
        else{
           hiddenWordNew += hiddenWordGame.charAt(k);
           }
          return hiddenWordNew;
              }
```

When it's ran, this is all I get (for the example, the word is "lamber"):

Letters already guessed:
Guess a letter in this word: -=--=- ??
l

Letters already guessed:
Guess a letter in this word: -=--=- ??
a

Letters already guessed:
Guess a letter in this word: -=--=- ??
m

Letters already guessed:
Guess a letter in this word: -=--=- ??
z

Letters already guessed:
Guess a letter in this word: -=--=- ??
/

Not a letter, guess again:
Letters already guessed:
Guess a letter in this word: -=--=- ??

---

Full code added here as there is a txt file it has to pull the words from (as part of the assignment) and then the actual masking of the word...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class WordGame2 {

static Random randomNum = new Random();

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
   
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   int numberGames = 1;
   int highScore;
   int avgScoreRunning;
   int avgScoreFinal;
   int currentScore;
   int numGuesses = '0';
   char anotherOne;
   char guess;
   String guessedLetters = "";
   String hiddenWordNew = "";
   String guessedLettersInc = "";
   String secret = "";
   String hiddenWordFinal = "";
   String wordLookup;
   String hiddenWordGame;
   String guessGame;

   
   
   
   
   
   System.out.print("Welcome to Words: The Word Guessing Game!\n");
   System.out.print("Play as many games as you like. I'll remember your top score.\n");
   System.out.print("and also compute your average for all games played.\n");
   
   
   do{
   numberGames++;
   
   wordLookup = findWord();
   System.out.println(wordLookup);
   hiddenWordGame = hideWord(wordLookup);
   System.out.println(hiddenWordGame);
   System.out.println("\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
      
   do{
   System.out.print("Letters already guessed: " + guessedLettersInc);
         System.out.println("\nGuess a letter in this word: " + hiddenWordGame + " ??");
         guess = keyboard.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(guess)){
               for (int l = 0; l < guessedLetters.length(); l++){
                  if (guessedLetters.charAt(l) == guess){
                  System.out.println ("==> a was already guessed.");
                  }
                  else if (Character.isAlphabetic(guess)){
                     for(int m = 0; m < guessedLettersInc.length(); m++){
                        if (guessedLettersInc.charAt(m) == guess){
                           guessedLettersInc = guessedLettersInc + guess;
                  }}}
                  else{
                     hiddenWordGame = hiddenWordNew;
                     guessedLetters = guessedLetters + guess;
                  }}}
            else{
               System.out.println("Not a letter, guess again:");
            }
   numGuesses++;            
   }
   while(hiddenWordNew != wordLookup);
   
   System.out.println("Want to play again? (Y/y for another): ");
      anotherOne = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
   }
   while (anotherOne == 'Y' || anotherOne == 'y');
   }
      public static String findWord() throws IOException
      {
         String secretWord = new String();
      
         File wordList = new File("wordlist.txt");
         Scanner wordListNew = new Scanner(wordList);
   
         int wordNumber = randomNum.nextInt(33735) +1;   
            
         for(int i = 1; i <= wordNumber; i++){
            secretWord = wordListNew.nextLine();
            if(i == wordNumber){
               }}
               return secretWord;
               }
               
       public static String hideWord(String wordLookup)
       {
         
         String hiddenWordFinal;
         
         int wordLength = wordLookup.length();
         System.out.println(wordLength);
         
         String hiddenWord = "";
         
         for (int j = 0; j < wordLookup.length(); j++)
            if(wordLookup.charAt(j) == 'a' || wordLookup.charAt(j) == 'e' || 
            wordLookup.charAt(j) == 'i' || wordLookup.charAt(j) == 'o' || 
            wordLookup.charAt(j) == 'u'){
               hiddenWord += "=";
            }
            else{
               hiddenWord += "-";
            }
            return hiddenWord;
            }
            
       public static String hiddenWordGame(String wordLookup, String hiddenWordGame, String guess, String hiddenWordNew)
       {
       
         for (int k = 0; k < wordLookup.length(); k++)
            if(wordLookup.charAt(k) == guess.charAt(0)){
               hiddenWordNew += guess.charAt(0);
               }
                 
            else{
               hiddenWordNew += hiddenWordGame.charAt(k);
               }
              return hiddenWordNew;
                  }
}
```

Comment: You output doesn't really match the code.  Consider providing a [mcve] which demonstrates your issue

Comment: I added the full code as I figured it's not too terribly large and required use of an external txt file. I appreciate you looking and your response

Comment: Can you explain exactly why you have this if statement? `if (guessedLettersInc.charAt(m) == guess){ guessedLettersInc = guessedLettersInc + guess; }`

Comment: This was to create a string of incorrect guesses, and to verify if the guess was in there already or not. Looking at it, it's definitely incomplete, I think I got too focused on the masking issue... But that you! I need to correct that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've run through your code and ...

- `while(hiddenWordNew != wordLookup);` is not how you compare `String`s
- you're not calling `hiddenWordGame`, so I'm not sure how `hiddenWordNew` is going to be getting updated
- you're calling `Character.isAlphabetic` twice, which is a waste
- ... and, you know what, a slightly different approach is in order

So, the basic idea is, you want to create some kind of "prompt" for the user, showing them what's been guessed and what hasn't.  This then becomes much simpler to manage, as you only need to "mask" the "master" word against the user guess and if they match, they user has guessed the word.

So, to start with, I changed your "masking" workflows:

```
public static String maskFor(char character) {
    if (character == 'a' || character == 'e'
            || character == 'i' || character == 'o'
            || character == 'u') {
        return "=";
    } else {
        return "-";
    }
}

public static String wordMask(String master, String guesses) {
    String mask = "";
    for (char character : master.toCharArray()) {
        if (guesses.indexOf(character) != -1) {
            mask += character;
        } else {
            mask += maskFor(character);
        }
    }
    return mask;
}
```

A quick sanity check using

```
System.out.println(wordMask("Java", ""));
System.out.println(wordMask("Java", "a"));
System.out.println(wordMask("Java", "av"));
System.out.println(wordMask("Java", "avp"));
System.out.println(wordMask("Java", "avj"));
System.out.println(wordMask("Java", "avjJ"));
```

prints

```
-=-=
-a-a
-ava
-ava
-ava
Java
```

Cool, step one is done.

Next, I changed your game loop.  This will basically

- Find a word
- Generate the first masking
- Prompt the user for input
- Check that's a "alphabet" character
- Update the user guesses
- Generate a new mask
- Compare the mask with the "master" and word and continue until you guess the word.

For example...

```
do {
    numberGames++;

    wordLookup = findWord();
    System.out.println("\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");

    guessedLetters = "";
    hiddenWordGame = wordMask(wordLookup, guessedLetters);
    do {
        System.out.println("\nGuess a letter in this word: " + hiddenWordGame + " ??");
        guess = keyboard.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        if (Character.isAlphabetic(guess)) {
            guessedLetters += guess;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a letter, guess again:");
        }
        numGuesses++;
        hiddenWordGame = wordMask(wordLookup, guessedLetters);
    } while (!hiddenWordGame.equals(wordLookup));

    System.out.println("Want to play again? (Y/y for another): ");
    anotherOne = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
} while (anotherOne == 'Y' || anotherOne == 'y');
```

Now, if you care, you can check to see if `guessedLetters` contains the `guess` as well, I didn't bother.

## Runnable example

I modified your `findWord` method to return a static word, makes testing much easier.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class WordGame2 {

    static Random randomNum = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numberGames = 1;
        int highScore;
        int avgScoreRunning;
        int avgScoreFinal;
        int currentScore;
        int numGuesses = '0';
        char anotherOne;
        char guess;
        String guessedLetters = "";
        String hiddenWordNew = "";
        String guessedLettersInc = "";
        String secret = "";
        String hiddenWordFinal = "";
        String wordLookup;
        String hiddenWordGame;
        String guessGame;

        System.out.print("Welcome to Words: The Word Guessing Game!\n");
        System.out.print("Play as many games as you like. I'll remember your top score.\n");
        System.out.print("and also compute your average for all games played.\n");

    do {
        numberGames++;

        wordLookup = findWord();
        System.out.println("\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");

        hiddenWordGame = wordMask(wordLookup, guessedLetters);
        do {
            System.out.println("\nGuess a letter in this word: " + hiddenWordGame + " ??");
            guess = keyboard.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

            if (Character.isAlphabetic(guess)) {
                guessedLetters += guess;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a letter, guess again:");
            }
            numGuesses++;
            hiddenWordGame = wordMask(wordLookup, guessedLetters);
        } while (!hiddenWordGame.equals(wordLookup));

        System.out.println("Want to play again? (Y/y for another): ");
        anotherOne = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    } while (anotherOne == 'Y' || anotherOne == 'y');
    }

    public static String findWord() throws IOException {
        return "word";
//        String secretWord = new String();
//
//        File wordList = new File("wordlist.txt");
//        Scanner wordListNew = new Scanner(wordList);
//
//        int wordNumber = randomNum.nextInt(33735) + 1;
//
//        for (int i = 1; i <= wordNumber; i++) {
//            secretWord = wordListNew.nextLine();
//            if (i == wordNumber) {
//            }
//        }
//        return secretWord;
    }

    public static String maskFor(char character) {
        if (character == 'a' || character == 'e'
                || character == 'i' || character == 'o'
                || character == 'u') {
            return "=";
        } else {
            return "-";
        }
    }

    public static String wordMask(String master, String guesses) {
        String mask = "";
        for (char character : master.toCharArray()) {
            if (guesses.indexOf(character) != -1) {
                mask += character;
            } else {
                mask += maskFor(character);
            }
        }
        return mask;
    }
}
```

> but the teacher isn't allowing them till next chapter (he specifically said we cannot use them...)

The basic logic still holds try if you just walk through each character of the `String`

```
public static String wordMask(String master, String guesses) {
    String mask = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < master.length(); index++) {
        char character = master.charAt(index);
        if (guesses.indexOf(character) != -1) {
            mask += Character.toString(character);
        } else {
            mask += maskFor(character);
        }
    }
    return mask;
}
```

And technically, a `String` is just a managed `char` array ;)

Comment: That's definitely a much better route to run it, and I wish we could use arrays, but the teacher isn't allowing them till next chapter (he specifically said we cannot use them...), even though it would make this assignment so much easier and more fluid. This is what has given me the most grief on this one!

Comment: @beansers See update

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry, first chance I've had to look, but this completely solves my masking issue, thank you again!